# What mathematical background do I need to know before study this books?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, book-recommendation

These are the textbooks adopted by my university in the course *"probability"*:

**Probability Theory:
The Logic of Science** *by
E. T. Jayn*

**An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications**, *by W. Feller*

According to the site of my university, we don´t need any high math background (calculus I, etc).

But i think it may be wrong.

We will study topics like kolmogorov probability, maxwell/poisson distribution and bayes formula.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Reading the preface (which you'll likely be able to see at their respective Amazon pages) will usually tell you the intended background

Comment: Checking that i can find some passages of calculus, but i can´t distinguish globally if they are essencial to the understanding of the topic.

Comment: Depending on how much you will cover of the textbooks, some (elementary) calculus may be needed in Feller's textbook, but you can still understand the topic without some of the calculations.